# after delete docker image, why can still find the deleted image by _catlog api?

Tags: docker

i have successfully delete the image.
(by DELETE :///v2//manifests/)

after delete the image

1. the deleted image's tag is null
2. when call /v2/_catalog api , still return the deleted image, why and how to solve it?

Comment: Why don't you use the ```docker rmi```?

Comment: i delete the image ,which is in the docker registry v2.

Comment: 【steps】
1、curl http://10.10.1.166:5000/v2/_catalog
2、curl http://10.10.1.166:5000/v2/busybox/tags/list
3、get Digest
curl --head -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" http://10.10.1.166:5000/v2/busybox/manifests/1.0
4、delete image
curl --head -X DELETE http://10.10.1.166:5000/v2/bus ... 3ab4d

【problem】

i have successfully the image from private docker registry.

but when i call http://ip:5000/v2/_catalog, i still can see the deleted image. it is not what i want to see. how to solve it, thanks?